# Mock environment variables for Amplify Function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I created an AWS Lambda function (named getDictionaryTranslation) with Amplify. The handler function look like:

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) { //eslint-disable-line
  const appId = process.env.APP_ID;
  const appKey = process.env.APP_KEY;
  context.done(null, `${appId}|${appKey}`);
};
```

Then I created a GraphQL Query from this function

```
type Query {
  getDictionaryTranslation(word: String!, lang: String!): String! @function(name: "getDictionaryTranslation-${env}")
}
```

We can set `APP_ID` and `APP_KEY` value on AWS Console by following this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg//env_variables.html

However, when running `amplify mock` in my local machine. How can I set these variables values?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

just create and store your .env variable on the root path of your function:

`amplify/backend/function/<function name>/.env`

So in your case:

`amplify/backend/function/getDictionaryTranslation/.env`

That will overwrite the env variables you added with the CLI and allow you to configure any runtime env variables for `amplify mock`, which also means in that .env file you need to have all the variables you set using the CLI for that specific cloud function.

More details on the doc: [Function mock environment variables](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/mock/#function-mock-environment-variables)

Comment: This does work. Just to add, the format for the .env file should be `VAR_NAME="some val"`. This will allow you to reference the value using `const val = process.env.VAR_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. I have two workarounds
1. hard code the API_KEY in lambda because the key value is a constant string
2. Add API_KEY as an environment variable in-cloudformation-template.json and pass the key value with the corresponding function-parameter.json file. This way is kind of hard coding as well.

Comment: Thank you, both of these approaches make API_KEY be revealed on source control (github, gitlab, .etc). Currently, I hardcoded these key and clear them every time I push code to source control.